# Cannot create sql server replication subscription due to timestamps and queued transactions, but that's not right

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-replication

In Sql Server 2005, we have a publication of a few tables.
This publication has 3 push subscriptions to DB2 databases (using connector from HIS2009) and has had for several months.
Attempting to add another subscription, virtually identical to the existing ones except it's a distinct server, we get:

```
SQL Server could not create a subscription for Subscriber 'MY-DATABASE-2'.
 An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
  OLE DB or ODBC Subscribers cannot subscribe to article 'my_table_1' in publication
  'my_publication' because the article has a timestamp column and the publication is
  'allow_queued_tran' (allows queued updating subscriptions). 
  The subscription could not be found.
  Microsoft SQL Server, Error 21249
```

However:

- my_table_1 does not contain a timestamp column
- The publication has allow_queued_tran = False
- There are other successful OLE-DB DB2 subscriptions on this publication
- The other tables in the publication do not contain timestamp. Some of them contain date columns, for which the DB2-equivalent type is "timestamp", but "timestamp" in DB2 just means (a date and time) - not a system-generated time marker.

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, we were able to create a new publication with the same tables, filters etc, and add new subscriptions to it.
So, it's resolved, though not really answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, but could not find solution. I removed existing subscription and publication, started over and then it worked. Very strange issue.